# Unable to call basic callbacks mastercard

Tags: payment-gateway, mastercard

Actually I have integrated with mastercard hosted checkout and it working properly.
https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html

But for further process I have to call basic callback for cancelling the payment and redirect the customer to merchnat site(like error, cancel , complete callback).

But I am unable to call those callback.

Comment: What do you mean you're unable to call the callback? What have you tried?

Comment: In callback function I have put my code( i.e. url and alert box) but those callbacks are not working on cancel payment or after payment completed redirect customer to the merchant site.

Comment: In the script tag you can have either functions or URL. 
`<script src="https://na-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/52/checkout.js"
                data-error="https://yoursite.com/error"
                data-cancel="https://yoursite.com/cancel">` 
When an event is triggered, the user is redirected to specific URL mentioned in the tag.

Comment: Yeah.I have tried this but it didn't work.I am using angular in front end.

Comment: Share your JavaScript

Comment: I have added functions in controller.And calling them in HTML using <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/52/checkout.js" data-cancel="cancelCallback" data-complete="completeCallback"></script>

Comment: @DikshaDhakate I am facing the same issue. Did you solve it ?

Comment: @Anzar No..it's not working they have issue in their callbacks

Comment: @DikshaDhakate I figured it out.

Comment: @Anzar How did you fix it?